# RegEx to match a certain element of an URL

Tags: regex, regex-group

Trying this in various forms but nothing is working so now its time to seek help,

I am using the following urls for my testing but require a RexEx to match against the -funsport- element and i just cant seem to get this to work.

> ```
> > https://livebackup-i-funsport-duma.aka.net
> > https://livemain-i-funsport-duma.aka.net
> > https://vod-i-funsport-duma.aka.net
> > https://clip-p-funsport-duma.aka.net
> ```

Everything i have tried so far is not returning a match that will work with my classifications, i am restricted by not being able to use wildcards otherwise i would simply return

> `.*-funsport-.*`

i know i am close on this and have tried various capturing groups both before and after the element i need however there is the possibility for it to be anything in free form so capture groups aren't the answer in the main.

Any ideas are amazingly well received.

Previously as above i have been able to use Capture Groups so to return something on this link

> t1-funsport-live-hls-prod.aka.net

I used the following to capture the known groups:

> /(se[1-9]-)?(t|m)(1|2|o)-funsport-(live|vod)-(hls|s|i)-(prod|az(dub|ams)).(aka|akahd).net/

Only this time the before and after textg can be free form and any markup of the text i just need to match against -funsport-

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Show the example output. For the first line it should be `livebackup-i-funsport-duma`?

Comment: Sorry this is for a Python device so in turn being written in Python as a backbone. the above links are just examples i have typed basically i need to match against anything that has -funsport- in the url. I cant use Wildcards due to processing power used on the device being excessive as we are going to be checking against vast numbers of urls.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you mean this

```
var test = ' https://livebackup-i-funsport-duma.aka.net  https://livemain-i-funsport-duma.aka.net  https://vod-i-funsport-duma.aka.net  https://clip-p-funsport-duma.aka.net'

test = test.match(/[-](\w+)[-](\w+)[.]/gmi)
test = test.join('\n')
test = test.replace(/(\w+)[.]/gmi,'')

console.log('test: ', test)
```

Output is
test: -funsport-
-funsport-
-funsport-
-funsport-